# Ui:inputselect selected value getting reset on page refresh

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have used ui:inputselect and its value is getting binded in do init but everytime on page load the value is getting reset.I am unable to preserve the selected value on page refresh .How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you share a minimal code sample of your controller and component it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Debarun, Please share the code.